# XNA 4.0 2D space shooter

Tags: xna, space, xna-4.0

I am a new first year student to XNA game studio. I have to make a game for this years course, nothing fancy its supposed to be a customized version of the Space Belt Assault game, the problem i have is the course is a find it out for yourself type and we have to add in multiplayer, 360 degree shooting capabilities and power ups for the players to pickup. I have to have two players able to play on the same screen, one with keyboard maybe other with mouse, I would like the asteroids destroyable and i really have no idea how to enable the Ship i have to shoot in 360 degree, or even turn at all. I am not looking for someone to write this game for me, I would just really like to know if anyone can give me some tips, maybe what i need to think about or where i can look on the web for relevant tutorials. To be honest I am just guessing at the moment and any help would be gratefully received. Thank you in advance Mark

Comment: To me these tutorials have been by far the most helpful when doing anything in XNA. http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/xna-tutorials Hopefully it will have what you need.

Comment: Thank you for replying, the site looks very good, i will look through it in detail tomorrow thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your friend and you as a game-developer (or any kind of programmer really) need to get to know that friend well.

Learning how to search for information is essential for any programmer and you should experiment with slight changes in your search-query and observe how it changes the result. (maybe even look for some tutorials on how to efficiently search with Google)

Now, just learning exactly what you need to get the project done is a bad practice so you should look for general tutorials to get you familiar with the basic concepts of XNA.
There is a guy called Riemer who has lots of great stuff and in particular a great introduction to XNA.
http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/series2d.php

This tutorial features per-pixel collision which i would usually not recommend since it is a lot of work for relatively bad performance but it is good as practice.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what if it is not absolutely necessary I wouldn´t recommend to create any game in XNA, it is long dead ant outdated framework, there is not reason to learn it or with it.

I know this isn´t exactly answer you was looking for, but there really isnt reason to start with XNA now.